# Change DIV text using javascript without Id and tagname

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code

```
<div class="points">
   <span>your points:</span>
   <div>29 P</div>
   <div>0 EXP</div>
</div>
```

I have a multiple DIV tags in my code and I want to change second div's text nametag or id code. Actually I want to replace this text with my code I have tried this using js a simple CSS injector

```
function injectCSS(str) {
    var node = document.createElement('style');
    node.innerHTML = str;
    document.body.appendChild(node);
}

injectCSS('div.points div:nth-child(2) { color: red } ');
injectCSS('div.points div:nth-child(2) { background: silver } ');
```

but this don't removes the text and lets me add new text

Comment: Abhinav, the code you posted does not suggest in any way that you are trying to set any text to any div element here. from what i see from your code is that you are trying to set forecolor and back color of the second child of points div. why do you think that any code you have posted should remove any text or add any text. 

And what you are trying to achive can be done with jquery easily

Answer (score 2):

I think you are close with using your function, but this can be accomplished with simply using JS `querySelector`:

```
<div class="points">
   <span>your points:</span>
   <div>29 P</div>
   <div>0 EXP</div>
</div>
```

and:

```
var str = "My String",
    el = document.querySelector('div.points div:nth-child(2)');

    el.innerHTML = str;
```

Once you have "HTML element" cached in variable, you can easily manipulate its other properties, like so:

`el.style.color = "red";`

PS. There is no need to pull **jQuery** for that.

```js
var str = "My String",
 el = document.querySelector('div.points div:nth-child(2)');
    
    el.innerHTML = str;
    el.style.color = "red";
```

```html
<div class="points">
   <span>your points:</span>
   <div>29 P</div>
   <div>0 EXP</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it really works my answer was using jQuery you helped me a lot

Comment: Unless you don't have some really heavy DOM manipulation to do, there is no need to resort to jQuery. There's similar native [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) methods, which you can take advantage of.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, this code works

```
$("div.points div:nth-child(2)").text("new text here");
```

No tagname or messy code simple one line of code
This also requires JQUERY